# ploting many files order on one line at gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have to plot 10 files with the same legend, but I also need to order the number inside the files, because when I write a line at gnuplot, it shows some bad image. Some numbers have to be before others to show a continue line on my graph. Looking to the red line it is possible to see what I mean. Is there some way to do that?

```
plot '<paste ../00/Statistic100.txt ../01/Statistic100.txt ../02/Statistic100.txt ../03/Statistic100.txt ../04/Statistic100.txt ../05/Statistic100.txt ../06/Statistic100.txt ../07/Statistic100.txt ../08/Statistic100.txt ../09/Statistic100.txt' with linespoint ls 1 title 'Reputation until 100%'
```

Thanks in advance!
Felipe

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `smooth unique` after the plot command.

From the [`gnuplot` documentation](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-310):

> The **unique** option makes the data monotonic in x; points with the same
>   x-value are replaced by a single point having the average y-value. The
>   resulting points are then connected by straight line segments.

## Example

### Without ordering

```
plot "-" with lines
 0   3
 2   4
-2   2
-5  -1
 1   5
 5   6
-1  -3
 4   0
-3  -3
 3  -4
-4   1
e
```

Result:

> [image]

### With ordering

```
plot "-" smooth unique with lines
 0   3
 2   4
-2   2
-5  -1
 1   5
 5   6
-1  -3
 4   0
-3  -3
 3  -4
-4   1
e
```

Result:

> [image]

Comment: +1 live and learn. This is so much better than fiddling with "borrowed" Linux commands!

Comment: @user154555 please mark the answer as best answer, if you believe it's worth of it, to remove the question from the unanswered queue.